# Configure cart rule in magento2?

Tags: magento-2.1, shopping-cart-price-rules, catalog-price-rules

I want to create a cart rule with the following conditions:

> Buy 3 products at £50 (Price of each product must be equal to £30).

How to do that.

Thanks.

Comment: (Any 3 products in the cart at £30). not getting this. Can you please explain scenario using example

Comment: There are many products added in the cart,  any 3 product price is exactly £30(The price of 3 products must be equal to 30 each.).